# Solr Nested Documents not properly setup

Tags: solr, solr8

I am trying to create a solr document with a child document. I am using solr 8.2.0
In order to comply with the instructions in https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/indexing-nested-documents.html#indexing-nested-documents , I added the following to schema.xml

```
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<fieldType name="nest_path" class="solr.NestPathField" />
<field name="_nest_path_" type="nest_path" />
<field name="_nest_parent_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

To create a test document, I used the following PHP code:

```
$solrClient = ...
$solrInputDocument = new SolrInputDocument();
$solrInputDocument->addField('id', 'yirmi1', 1);
$solrInputDocument->addField('test_s', 'this is a parent test', 1);
$childDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
$childDoc->addField('id', 'yirmi2', 1);
$childDoc->addField('test_s', 'this is a child test', 1);
$solrInputDocument->addChildDocument($childDoc);
$solrUpdateResponse = $solrClient->addDocument($solrInputDocument);
$solrClient->commit();
```

When I query for `fq=id: "yirmi1"` or `fq=id: "yirmi2"`,
the records come up, but there is no indication that there are parent or child documents.  Also, when querying for the fields `_nest_parent_`, `_nest_path_`, and `_root_` do not come up, even when I specify them as query fields.

What else do I have to set up to properly create nested documents.

Comment: Hey, any success with adding child document? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Apparently "anonymous" or "unlabelled" child documents and `_nest_path_` do not mix well together.

I think you have 2 options:

A)

If you want to use addChildDocument, you will need to remove `_nest_path_` and `_nest_parent_` fields from your schema.

B)

Set the parent-child relation like you would set any other field:

```
$solrInputDocument->addField('child', $childDoc);
```

Comment: I tried both with _nest_path_ and without, both with  `addChildDocument()` and `addField('child')`  -- and still no sign of child document when query returns parent document.

Comment: If you want to include the children in results you need to use ChildDocTransformerFactory

Comment: $solrInputDocument->addField('child', $childDoc);
this does not work.. do we have any solution for this in php ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `fl=*,[child]` ?
That should return *childDocuments* .

I will admit that I'm new to SOLR and I haven't had 100% success with this. :(

Comment: This does not work here.  The child is still not showing on the parent document.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Solr 8.5.1, documents added via Data Import Handler with nested entities from PostgreSQL) the `_childDocuments_` are only included in the response if the schema.xml does not contain the `_nest_path_` field and field type.

`_nest_parent_` can be removed from the schema as well, since it is not populated as far as I observed.

A `_root_` field is required in the schema:

```
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="false" />
```

It worked best by adding some sort of type information to the documents, e.g. `entitytype` as in the following example:

```
...
$solrInputDocument = new SolrInputDocument();
$solrInputDocument->addField('id', 'yirmi1', 1);
$solrInputDocument->addField('entitytype', 'parent', 1);
$solrInputDocument->addField('test_s', 'this is a parent test', 1);
$childDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
$childDoc->addField('id', 'yirmi2', 1);
$childDoc->addField('entitytype', 'child', 1);
$childDoc->addField('test_s', 'this is a child test', 1);
$solrInputDocument->addChildDocument($childDoc);
...
```

and then querying with the following parameters:

```
q=entitytype:parent
fl=*,[child parentFilter=entitytype:parent]
```